# Fortify race condition in servlet

Tags: java, servlets, fortify

I'm getting the following abstract for several similar lines of code:

> The class LabResult is a singleton, so the member field testname is
>   shared between users. The result is that one user could see another
>   user's data.

Where this is the line of code:

```
public void setTestname(String testname) {
    this.testname = testname;
}
```

I have 57 of these errors since this is happening in almost every form. Is there really a security error here?

Answer (score 2):

I assume that code you showed is part of the class `LabResult`. From the name of the class, I'd guess you create more than just one object of that class, so you don't want to use a singleton (which is a class restricted to only one instance of itself). Otherwise, one user will set the fields in that class, and then another user will overwrite that data, and then the first user will get back the other user's data. Probably not what you want.

Comment: The information is meant to be shared, so I'd assume it would then be okay to be used from a singleton.

Comment: I was only guessing based on the limited info you provided. If you provide more information about that class (what it is, how it is used, etc), then people can provide better advice.

Answer (score 2):

Essentially any instance variable should be constant, that is 'static final' but in case your instance  variable does not have a final value we can declare your testname as below

```
private static volatile testname;
```

Details can be found here.
[Race condition - field member issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38757923/how-to-fix-fortify-race-condition-singleton-member-field-issue)