# How to fix Fortify Race Condition: Singleton Member Field issue

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, fortify

I encounter a problem.
we use Spring MVC framework in my Project,but Spring MVC default Controller is Singleton Model.
I change Controller use @Scope("session") by session to  avoid race Condition problem(everyone has own Controller).

```
@Controller
@Scope("session")
public class AP0Controller extends BaseController {

    @Autowired
    GnRecService gnRecService;

    Integer seq = null;//Global variable

    @RequestMapping(value = "/agn/AP1W01A_004", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView welcomeGrid(@RequestParam("payType")String payType){
        seq = gnRecService.findTheLastPK(payType);
        ModelAndView view = new ModelAndView(".agn.AP1W01A_004");
        return view;
    }

    public ModelAndView showPk() {
        seq +=2; 
        ModelAndView view = new ModelAndView(".agn.AP1W01A_004");
        view.addObject("seq",seq)
        return view;
    }

}
```

After Scanned By HP Fortify,the report indicated this will cause Race Condition.
How can I fix it and pass the issue?

```
seq +=2;//Race Condition: Singleton Member Field
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try do redesign your controller to not put state in it. 
Alternatively you can think about using AtomicInteger

```
AtomicInteger seq = new AtomicInteger();//Global variable

@RequestMapping(value = "/agn/AP1W01A_004", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView welcomeGrid(@RequestParam("payType")String payType){
        seq.set(gnRecService.findTheLastPK(payType));
        ModelAndView view = new ModelAndView(".agn.AP1W01A_004");
        return view;
    }

    public ModelAndView showPk() {
        final int localSeq = seq.addAndGet(2); 
        ModelAndView view = new ModelAndView(".agn.AP1W01A_004");
        view.addObject("seq",localSeq)
        return view;
    }
```

Comment: If the variable seq was java.lang.String type or POJO,how to fix?thank you

Comment: @HamiltonLin: you can read more on java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicReference

Answer (score 2):

Race condition occurs when we declare an instance variable in a class and use the same in any of the method inside the same class.

```
 public class Test {  
 private boolean isRaceCondition;
 private String  myRaceCondition;
 public  void testMyMethod(){
 If(isRaceCondition){
     myRaceCondition= "Yes It is";
    }
   else{
       myRaceCondition= "No It is not";
   }
  }}
```

The above code will run correctly in single threaded environment but in multithreaded environment, it is possible that more than one thread is working on the same piece of code and can cause data integrity issue.

For example Thread T1 set the value of  isRaceCondition= true but before T1 can execute the method testMyMethod(), another thread T2 reset the value of isRaceCondition= false so now when T1 try to execute the testMyMethod() it will see isRaceCondition to false and it will set myRaceCondition= “No It is not”;

To resolve this issue, the simplest solution is 
In case we can set initial value to variable and essentially they are constant.

```
private static final boolean isRaceCondition=True;
private static final  String  myRaceCondition="Yes It is" ;
```

Otherwise in case we CANNOT set initial value, we use **volatile**. This will ensure that value of variable is always fetched from memory before they are used

```
private static volatile boolean isRaceCondition;
private static volatile  String  myRaceCondition;
```

Answer (score 1):

For String and other object race condition we should we AtomicReference race condition.for example private AtomicReference name and generate setters and getters and simillarly for user defined objects AtomicReference person and generate setters and getters for this your race condition is solved.

Comment: private AtomicReference<String> name; setters and getters for this

Comment: public AtomicReference<String> getName()
{
return name;
}
public void setName(AtomicReference<String> name) 
{
this.name = name;
}

Comment: Simillary for User Defined Objects :

Comment: private AtomicReference<Person> person;
public void setPerson(AtomicReference<Person>  person)
{
this.person = person
}
public AtomicReference<Person> getPerson(){
return person;
}

Comment: Kindly edit your Answer with any information that is pertinent to your Answer. All comments may be removed at any time.