# Volatile and Synchronized to Solve Race Condition: Singleton Member Field

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronized, volatile

I was having some problem trying to understand and fix errors reported from Fortify scan. I have this class:

```
public class DaoImpl extends BaseDaoImpl {
    private static volatile String sNric;
    
    synchronized private void setInfo(InfoTO pers) {
        sNric = pers.getNRIC();
    }

    synchronized public InfoTO getInfo() { 
        InfoTO pers = new InfoTO();
        sNric = retrieveDetail();
        pers.setNRIC(sNric);
    }

    synchronized private String retrieveDetail() {
        // some logic to get info from database
    }
}
```

My code was originally without the `static volatile` and `synchronized` keyword. And Fortify was reporting `Race Condition: Singleton Member Field` warning at the variable declaration of `sNric` as well as `sNric = retrieveDetail();`

I went to research and found [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38757923/how-to-fix-fortify-race-condition-singleton-member-field-issue). However, I am not very sure on the concept of volatile with synchronized. Will the proposed solution above causing some deadlock issue?

Comment: please check Stephen C's answer. I have deleted mine as it was incorrect

Comment: Thread safety of shared variables is about *visibility* and *atomicity* of state transitions.  The `volatile` keyword is a weak form of synchronization that deals **only** with visibility and can't help with other atomicity or race concerns.  If you are already fully synchronizing transitions of shared state, then the `volatile` keyword adds nothing else of use to a concurrent system.

Comment: Why do you cache `sNric` yet when needing it in `retrieveDetail` you turn to a database instead of that cache?

Comment: `volatile` is not going to save you from a _race_, it isn't about that. you need to make a clear distinction between visibility and atomicity, or both.

Comment: Why is `sNric` static? Given it is only accessed through non-static methods, I would think that field should be non-static as well. The race condition would occur if there are multiple instances of `DaoImpl`, because your methods synchronize on an instance, while the field is static.

Comment: Adding to what Eugene said: If two threads "race" to access a variable, the `volatile` keyword can affect the order in which the accesses effectively happen, but it does not change the fact that the threads are "racing."

Comment: @MarkRotteveel the bigger question is, why does this variable exist at all? The only read is immediately preceded by a write, so `sNric = retrieveDetail(); pers.setNRIC(sNric);` could be replaced by `pers.setNRIC(retrieveDetail());`, demonstrating that `setInfo`’s write to `sNric` has no effect at all, no-one ever reads that value.

Comment: @Holger Although true, I assumed that was a result of simplification of the code when I posted my comment.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel a code simplification that affects when which variable is accessed would be a no-go for a question about thread safety. As data access is what thread safety (the prevention of data races) is all about…

Comment: @Holger Then vote to close.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel we don’t know whether such oversimplification truly happened. It’s also possible that the OP’s real code is as pointless as shown here. That would not be a close reason.

Answer (score 2):

The "concept" of `volatile` with `synchronized` is that you probably shouldn't do it.

If you use `synchronized` in all of the methods that access and update a shared variable (such as your `sNric` variable) then declaring the `volatile` is redundant and inefficient.

As to your question about deadlocks, I cannot see any way that you could get deadlocks based solely on the code above.  **However**, you haven't shown us the code for the `InfoTO` or the code that uses these classes.  It is not impossible for a deadlock to occur involving the `DaoImpl` instance lock and other locks.

If you are concerned that `getInfo` calling `this.retrieveDetail` might deadlock.  There is only one (`DaoImpl` instance) lock involved here, and Java primitive locks are reentrant.  (A thread will not be blocked if it tries to acquire a primitive lock that it already holds.)

Finally, you should if you are concerned about thread-safety, check that `setNRIC` and `getNRIC` are thread-safe.  If they are not, I don't think that the above is handling the `InfoTo` objects safely.

---

Note that you cannot reason about the thread-safety of a class unless you take account of the other classes that it depends on AND the way that it used / intended to be used.

Comment: @hyperfkcb, Please check this answer. My (deleted) answer was incorrect.

Comment: @hyperfkcb - Horse has asked me to @ tag you to let you know that we found a flaw in his answer and he has decided to delete it (for now at least).

Comment: I see I see so the volatile and synchronized is advisable not to be used together in this case? Yes, I am afraid of the 3 functions above might cause some deadlock as they kept waiting for each other due to synchronized modifier.

Comment: I read your comments earlier on, so as long as other classes that invoke the function above is not 'static', deadlock will not occur, am I right?

Comment: Using synchronized + volatile won't cause a deadlock.  (The `volatile` keyword has no locking semantics, explicit or implicit.)  The possible deadlock I am talking about would be due to other things.

Comment: No.  That is not right.  My comments earlier were to say that `static` is not a guarantee of no deadlocks.  I did not say (and it is not true that) non-static methods avoid deadlock either.  You can get deadlocks with static methods, non-static methods or a mixture of both.  Deadlocks happen when two or more threads are using two or more locks and they try to acquire them in a different order.

Comment: `setNRIC` doesn’t need to be thread safe, as it is invoked on a newly created local object. But there’s a special thing about the OP’s code, `sNric` is only written, never read except in the `sNric = retrieveDetail(); pers.setNRIC(sNric);` sequence, that could (and should) use a local variable instead. Then, `getInfo()` wouldn’t need `synchronized`. The `setInfo` method is entirely pointless anyway, so it’s irrelevant whether `getNRIC()` is thread safe. Whether `retrieveDetail()` need synchronization depends on whether it depends on some mutable state not shown in the question.

Answer (score 1):

You have not really given enough information and code details for a certain Answer. But I will give it a shot.

## `AtomicReference`

To quote the [comment above by scottb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66111969/volatile-and-synchronized-to-solve-race-condition-singleton-member-field#comment116886528_66111969):

> Thread safety of shared variables is about *visibility* and *atomicity* of state transitions.

I often prefer the use of [the `Atomic…` classes](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/atomic/package-summary.html) to address both visibility and atomicity. These classes can provide an alternative to `volatile` and `synchronized`.

In this case, we can use [`AtomicReference`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicReference.html) class to hold as its payload a reference to your current desired `String` value. Notice that we mark it `final` as the reference to the `AtomicReference` object itself will never change. Its payload, a reference (pointer) taking us to the desired `String` object, *does* change. At one moment it may point to the `String` value `"dog"` while a moment later it may point to the `String` value `"cat"`. But the container of either `String` is always the very same `AtomicReference` object, a wrapper around that contained text, that contained `String` object.

If your `InfoTO` class looked like this:

```java
package work.basil.example;

public class InfoTO
{
    private String nric ;

    public String getNric ( ) { return this.nric; }

    public void setNric ( String nric ) { this.nric = nric; }
}
```

…then your `DaoImpl` might look something like this:

```java
package work.basil.example;

import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicReference;

public class DaoImpl
{
    private AtomicReference < String > sNric;

    private void setInfo ( InfoTO pers )
    {
        this.sNric.set( pers.getNric() );
    }

    public InfoTO getInfo ( )
    {
        InfoTO pers = new InfoTO();
        String s = retrieveDetail();
        pers.setNric( s );
        return pers ;
    }

    private String retrieveDetail ( )
    {
        return this.sNric.get();
    }
}
```

Your lines:

```java
        sNric = retrieveDetail();
        pers.setNRIC(sNric);
```

…do not make sense to me. You use a field to hold what is a temporary value. So I substituted a local variable instead.

Your `retrieveDetail` method makes no sense to me. You seem to be returning from calls to a database the very same string value you are caching in the field `sNric`. So I changed that method to access the cached field `sNric`. This seems more consistent with your intended logic, and more importantly, shows both the getter and setter of the `AtomicReference` in action.

Of course, as others said, you may well have other thread-safety issues in the substantial code you did not show us.

Comment: You have it backwards. The entire caching was pointless, as the cached value has never been used, as you correctly noticed, the value passed to `setNric` always originated from an immediately preceding call to `retrieveDetail()`. But it is not a fix to remove the actual database operation. Besides that, an `AtomicReference` variable need to be initialized.